# Job is not run after Manual Validation

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

The scenario: If "doSomething" fails then "waitforValidation" must run. After succeful validation then "doSomethingAfterValidation" must run.
But currently after succesful validation "doSomethingAfterValidation" is simply Skipped. If I remove "condition: failed()" and make "doSomething" succeed there is no problem.
Tried playing with conditions with no luck...

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

jobs:
- job: doSomething
  displayName: Do Something
  steps:
  - script: script that will fail
    displayName: 'Run a online script'

- job: waitforValidation
  displayName: Wait for external validation
  dependsOn: doSomething
  condition: failed()
  pool: server
  timeoutInMinutes: 4320
  steps:

  - task: ManualValidation@0
    timeoutInMinutes: 1440
    inputs:
     notifyUsers: x@x.com
     instructions: 'Please validate'
     onTimeout: 'resume'

- job: doSomethingAfterValidation
  displayName: do something after Validation
  dependsOn: waitForValidation
  steps:
  - script: echo Extecuted after resume!
    displayName: 'Run a script after manual validation'
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to insert the condition `succeeded(‘waitForEvaluation’)` in `doSomethingAfterValidation`. specifying the job in question. Since the dependencies are in the same dependency tree, `succesful()` applies to all jobs. And since one fails, it will skip `doSomethingAfterValidation`. Not very logical IMO, but there it is.

Answer (score 0):

> Job is not run after Manual Validation

You could try to add the condition `succeededOrFailed()` for the job `doSomethingAfterValidation`.

```
- job: doSomethingAfterValidation
  displayName: do something after Validation
  dependsOn: waitForValidation
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  steps:
  - script: echo Extecuted after resume!
    displayName: 'Run a script after manual validation'
```

The `succeededOrFailed` means that job will be executed even if a previous dependency has failed, unless the run was canceled.

Please check the document [Specify conditions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) for some more details.

Comment: problem is when using succeededOrFailed "doSomethingAfterValidation" is still run even though I reject the Manual validation